# Executing BC Calculations from C#

Tags: c#, c, bc

i'm writing an app that needs a calculation support (Fun project). However, is there a way to enter input data to the interactive console in BC from C#, and then read the data from the console with C#? I have tried to use dllexport in the c source, but the code is confusing me.

Comment: I have tried to make my own version of the main() function with dllexport, but the function is confusing me. (it calls yyparse, and it doesnt look like it loads any code or files). If i could get the C part to work, then i can do the C# part myself :)

Comment: Post the part which you do not understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way to interact with prewritten console applications in c# is to use [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s.aspx) and then redirect [`StandardInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput.aspx) and [`StandardOutput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx).

Comment: Thank you! Now i'll just have to experiment with it :)